# is it possible to have a loginVC and anotherVC in Mac OS menu bar app?

Tags: ios, macos, swift3, menubar

I come from ios development and trying to build a macOS menu bar app for my IOS App but the way user can see any data is after login so is it possible to have View Controllers in a menu bar app so that when user logins he/she is directed to the datascreen? Its just a basic app so i want this to stay on the menu bar only.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, You can create a app which will open from menu bar and you can operate that from there. Check this [repo link](https://github.com/taichino/PopupTest/tree/master/PopupTest). They open a viewController with SearchBar in that.

Comment: @Surjeet thanks for the comment , i know how to open one VC but my question was doing something similar like in ios say through loginVC i do a segue to another VC after successful login can this be done in a menu bar app?